# Using my own login page for a password-protected Apache web directory

Tags: apache, login-control

I have a password-protected Apache web directory.  Is there any way to access it with my own login page, instead of the standard browser login pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no - the authentication is handled by the browser which serves you the popup. If you want to use HTTP basic auth you'll have to live with the ugly popup.

If you want to protect it using some other auth mechanism (e.g. something common would be against a user table and using cookies for a session identifier) then you'd have to write a small application that handles the auth and exposes the files in the directory when you want them to.

Comment: @James- thanks.  Can you recommend any simple auth mechanisms to replace HTTP basic auth?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=implementing+simple+login+with+php+sessions&btnG=Google+Search or maybe try Zend Framework's Zend_Auth